# neo4j match node with multipal nodes connected to him, return them as array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Assuming a node for this example a User has many friends (they are Users aswell)
lets assume as well that im looking the user by id which is unique.

How can i query to get one row back with a property of friends as array?
Example:

`MATCH (user:User {id: "some-id"})-[:FriendsWith]->(friend:User)
RETURN user, friend`

Now I expected the result to be an array of length one,
like this `[{user: data, friend: [array of users]}]`

But instade I got rows [{user: , friend:}, {user, friend: }]
the `user` was duplicated in each row..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`collect` function](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html#aggregation-collect) to create a collection:

```
MATCH (user:User {id: "some-id"})-[:FriendsWith]->(friend:User)
RETURN user, collect(friend.name) AS friends
```

There is an implicit group by when using an aggregation.